# Is there a way for me to count the number of autoID's below a given autoID in swift firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently making a chat module that counts the number of messages that the user has not read. The user has a child "LatestReadMessage" with the ID of the latest message he has seen before exiting the viewController. What I want is to count the ID's below the value of "LatestReadMessage". To make things clearer here is an example:

"LatestReadMessage" has the value of: -LfZ1gZ7EUCosK9JlZ0b

The id's inside of my messages node are:

```
messages:
    -LfZ1fdWF-AVQMnL9b6y 
    -LfZ1gZ7EUCosK9JlZ0b //the id of LatestReadMessage
    -LfZ1kXNajjLNZXBi_Bh
    -LfZ1nMx1M8soMYJ5Da7
    -LfZ1o_1mUYS8QN3KbyX
    -LfZ1q61SMR96l7L0BOb 
    -LfZ1rdSkmfL8OLVAq7K
```

What I want to get is the number of ID's below -LfZ1gZ7EUCosK9JlZ0b (e.g -LfZ1kXNajjLNZXBi_Bh,  -LfZ1nMx1M8soMYJ5Da7 and etc.) is there a way for me to filter and count the ID's below it?

Comment: Maybe you can create a separate child named `count` under your user which has 2 elements, `count_seen` and `total_count`. Btw if you are working on real time chat app, I recommend you should see [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq). Some great help in those videos.

Comment: You could fetch them and count them as they come in. Of course this is only a solution if you only need the number after fetching all users...

Comment: Be careful with 'below' and 'above'. You should really have a child node in each *read: true* of you're not doing that already. There are a number of solutions; as @Mihir mentioned, keeping a separate child node of the count is one option, the second option is to query for all of the unread nodes and use .childrenCount as shown here [DataSnapshot.childrenCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323955/swift-4-and-firebase-how-to-count-child-values). This question has been asked a number of times before so searching here on SO will reveal a number of solutions.